# 3D Matrix as Mark To market Cube for finance in TikzPicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-graphdrawing

this isn't my first language), I am just starting out with the tikzpicture environment. Can anyone show me a better method to implement this
[image]
I would also like to have the smaller arrow pointer
and center the elements in all arrays without doing it manually :)

I post my horrible code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[italian]{babel}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz} % TikzPictures
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        %\begin{center}
            \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt  
            \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
            
            % Shape: Rectangle 
            \draw   (200,100) -- (350,100) -- (350,250) -- (200,250) -- cycle ;
            
            % Straight Lines 
            \draw    (230,100) -- (230,250) ;
    
            \draw    (260,100) -- (260,250) ;
    
            \draw    (290,100) -- (290,250) ;
    
            \draw    (320,100) -- (320,250) ;
    
            \draw    (200,130) -- (350,130) ;
    
            \draw    (200,160) -- (350,160) ;
    
            \draw    (200,190) -- (350,190) ;
    
            \draw    (200,220) -- (350,220) ;
    
            \draw    (220,80) -- (220,100) ;
    
            \draw    (220,80) -- (370,80) ;
    
            \draw    (350,230) -- (370,230) ;
    
            \draw    (240,60) -- (240,80) ;
    
            \draw    (240,60) -- (390,60) ;
    
            \draw    (250,80) -- (250,100) ;
    
            \draw    (370,80) -- (370,230) ;
    
            \draw    (310,80) -- (310,100) ;
    
            \draw    (340,80) -- (340,100) ;
    
            \draw    (280,80) -- (280,100) ;
    
            \draw    (350,110) -- (370,110) ;
    
            \draw    (370,90) -- (390,90) ;
    
            \draw    (350,140) -- (370,140) ;
    
            \draw    (350,170) -- (370,170) ;
    
            \draw    (350,200) -- (370,200) ;
    
            \draw    (300,60) -- (300,80) ;
    
            \draw    (270,60) -- (270,80) ;
    
            \draw    (330,60) -- (330,80) ;
    
            \draw    (360,60) -- (360,80) ;
    
            \draw    (390,60) -- (390,210) ;
    
            \draw    (370,120) -- (390,120) ;
    
            \draw    (370,150) -- (390,150) ;
    
            \draw    (370,180) -- (390,180) ;
    
            \draw    (370,210) -- (390,210) ;
     
            % arrow L(w)
            \draw    (190,100) -- (190,247) ;
            \draw [shift={(190,250)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
            
            % arrow time
            \draw    (200,260) -- (347,260) ;
            \draw [shift={(350,260)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
    
            % arrow surface
            \draw [line width=0.75]    (360,260) -- (407.88,212.12) ;
            \draw [shift={(410,210)}, rotate = 135] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
            
            
            
    
            %------------------------------------------ X matrix time 
            \draw (295,110.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$ \dotsc $};
    
            \draw (209,110.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{0}$};
    
            \draw (239,110.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{1}$};
    
            \draw (269,110.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{2}$};
    
            \draw (330,110.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$T$};
            %-------------------------------------------
            
            %------------------------------------------- Y matrix time
            % Text Node
            \draw (350,85) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$T$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (289,85) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{2}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (259,85) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{1}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (229,85) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{0}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (317,88.5) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$ \dotsc $};
            % Text Node
            %-------------------------------------------
            
            %------------------------------------------- Z matrix time
            \draw (369,64.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$T$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (308,64.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{2}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (278,64.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{1}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (248,64.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$t_{0}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (336,68) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$ \dotsc $};
            
            
            % Text Node
            \draw (250,262) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize] [align=left] {tempo};
            
            
            % Text Node
            \draw (172,179) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize,rotate=-270] [align=left] {$\displaystyle L( \omega )$};
            
            
            % Text Node
            \draw (387,238) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize] [align=left] {surface};
            
            
            % Text Node
            \draw (349,209.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$y_{\omega _{N}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (349,119.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$y_{\omega _{1}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (349,149.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$y_{\omega _{2}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (369,127.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$z_{\omega _{2}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (369,97.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$z_{\omega _{1}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (369,187.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$z_{\omega _{N}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (295,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\ddots $};
            % Text Node
            \draw (325,226.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{N}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (235,135.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{1}}^{t_{1}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (325,136.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{1}}^{T}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (211,190) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\vdots $};
            % Text Node
            \draw (205,135.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{1}}^{t_{0}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (205,165.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{2}}^{t_{0}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (205,225.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{N}}^{t_{0}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (265,135.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{1}}^{t_{2}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (295,135.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\dotsc $};
            % Text Node
            \draw (235,165.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{2}}^{t_{1}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (265,165.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{2}}^{t_{2}}$};
            % Text Node
            \draw (325,166.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$x_{\omega _{2}}^{T}$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        %\end{center}
        \caption{Mark~to~market~cube}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome :) // A hint: many times the links to the right (Related) provide useful links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, pseudo 3D with plain TikZ is enough. Even I don't use different `layer`s, just use the natural order of drawing command to make some scopes: draw first, appear first! Three `scope`s are 3 layers - `matrix` nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{matrixlayer/.style={
matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw=#1,fill=#1!15,minimum size=10mm,anchor=center,text=black},
column sep=-.5*\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-.5*\pgflinewidth
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\begin{scope}[shift={(45:2)}]
\node[matrixlayer=red] (m3){
t_0& t_1 & t_2 & \cdots & T\\
z_{\omega_1}^{t_0}&z_{\omega_1}^{t_1}&z_{\omega_1}^{t_2}&\cdots&z_{\omega_1}^T \\
z_{\omega_2}^{t_0}&z_{\omega_2}^{t_1}&z_{\omega_2}^{t_2}&\cdots&z_{\omega_2}^T \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
z_{\omega_N}^{t_0}&z_{\omega_N}^{t_1}&z_{\omega_N}^{t_2}&\cdots&z_{\omega_N}^T \\
};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(45:1)}]
\node[matrixlayer=teal] (m2){
t_0& t_1 & t_2 & \cdots & T\\
y_{\omega_1}^{t_0}&y_{\omega_1}^{t_1}&y_{\omega_1}^{t_2}&\cdots&y_{\omega_1}^T \\
y_{\omega_2}^{t_0}&y_{\omega_2}^{t_1}&y_{\omega_2}^{t_2}&\cdots&y_{\omega_2}^T \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
y_{\omega_N}^{t_0}&y_{\omega_N}^{t_1}&y_{\omega_N}^{t_2}&\cdots&y_{\omega_N}^T \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\node[matrixlayer=blue] (m1){
t_0& t_1 & t_2 & \cdots & T\\
x_{\omega_1}^{t_0}&x_{\omega_1}^{t_1}&x_{\omega_1}^{t_2}&\cdots&x_{\omega_1}^T \\
x_{\omega_2}^{t_0}&x_{\omega_2}^{t_1}&x_{\omega_2}^{t_2}&\cdots&x_{\omega_2}^T \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x_{\omega_N}^{t_0}&x_{\omega_N}^{t_1}&x_{\omega_N}^{t_2}&\cdots&x_{\omega_N}^T \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[->,thick]
\draw ([shift={(0,-.3)}]m1.south west)--([shift={(0,-.3)}]m1.south east) node[midway,below]{tempo};
\draw ([shift={(.5,0)}]m1.south east)--([shift={(.5,0)}]m3.south east) node[midway,right]{surface};
\draw ([shift={(-.3,0)}]m1.north west)--([shift={(-.3,0)}]m1.south west) node[midway,rotate=90,above]{$L(\omega)$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for all tips :)